# How to get printThis.js to run a script after print or if print was cancelled

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to get [PrintThis.js](https://jasonday.github.io/printThis/) to run a script after printing, even if the print dialog is cancelled.
In my specific instance, I have to change the colspan on a TD before the print, and want to put it back when done.

Here is the code I've tried but it has no discernable effect at all.

```
$("#cInfoSpan").attr("colspan",4);
$(".printSpan").attr("colspan",2);

u=uniqueNumber();
$("#chemOrderWrapper").printThis({
    importCSS: false,
    loadCSS: "../css/printBlankChem.css?ver="+u,
    afterPrint:function(){                  
                $("#cInfoSpan").attr("colspan",5);
                $(".printSpan").attr("colspan",1);
    },
    beforePrintEvent:function(){
            console.log( "before pre");
    }
});
```